# Samsung WF45K6500AV front load washer trips the breaker immediately when plugged in

Tags: circuit-breaker, washer

3 year old Samsung WF45K6500AV front load washer trips the breaker immediately when plugged in - power on button isn't pushed so I have no chance to read an error code.   [image]

When connector CN11 is disconnected from the main PCB, the breaker will not trip.  But the machine won't turn on either.  Was hoping to get an error code but no luck.    Because all wiring is contained in the harness I can't follow the line to see where it goes.  Any idea what connector CN11 goes to?  If I can't find out, I'll just have to remove the cover from the wire harness to expose the individual wires. 20A AFCI Breaker verified good, no wet components seen, and no exposed wiring found anywhere.

Comment: Breaker tripping as soon as something is plugged in usually means a bad short.  Would plug in something else to check the wires in the wall, but it is probably in the machine.  L line on CN11 should be hot/live wire.  Problem is probably some wire insulation broken touching the metal casing, maybe near the door.

Comment: Please provide a resistance reading from each pin on the cable to chassis ground, testing with door open, and again with door closed.  It sounds like a plain old ground fault.  What error code is the AFCI breaker reading out? (you may have to google how to get it).

Comment: If. you leave the door open does it power up

Comment: The error code on the washer (if any) is not going to help you diagnose this.

Comment: From the label it would appear the CN11 may go to a microswitch that breaks the line when the door is open.  Which would explain why the breaker won't trip, as the power is disconnected.

Comment: Siemens AFCI has one light come on when turned back on meaning "arc fault not associated with ground."  I have two washers side by side with two separate breakers.  One machine works fine on both breakers, this problem machine trips both breakers.

Comment: Resistance from both pins to ground is OL (open loop) and from pin to pin is also OL.  So doesn't appear to be any short to chassis or between the pins.  Still trips with door open or shut.  Removed the door lock altogether and nothing changed in resistance readings or breaker tripping behavior

Comment: The cable connecting to CN11 has a black and white wire.  White pin to the Hot prong on the plug is 0.2 Ohms, white pin to neutral is 466 kOhms, and white to ground is OL.  Black to all three plug prongs is OL.

Comment: SO... thoughts while sleeping on it.  Considered that instead of CN11 being output power as I initially thought, it was input power because White wire to Hot was 0.2 Ohms.  But if that was true then black wire to Neutral should also be less than 1 ohm.  Instead it's OL.  This suggests there is a short between the white wire and the Hot input. 
 The resistance between the two CN11 pins on the board is 28MOhms so I don't believe the problem is on the board.  So what is that white wire connected to?